# Pyautogui : Autoclicker with Image recognition How do I make a function I made only run if an image is recognised?

Tags: python, automation, image-recognition, pyautogui

I'm new in python and I know my code is really messy . I need help , I wanted the function below to only run If an Image I set is recognised `mc_ok_button.png`  but it's kind of confusing because I want it to join with a loop I already made . If I place the code in the loop wouldn't it not run the rest of the functions below it ?

My image recognition function :

```
import pyautogui as pg
import pydirectinput as pd
import time

ax,ay = pg.locateCenterOnScreen('mc_ok_button.png',confidence=.6)

def function_when_restart():
    print(ax,ay)
    pd.click(ax,ay)
    print('Waiting to return back to the server...')
    time.sleep(8)
    pd.moveTo(892,531)
    print('finding server...')
    pd.click()
    print('connecting to the server...')

function_when_restart()
```

Then I want the `function_when_restart()` function to only run if the `mc_ok_button.png` image is recognised and make `project()` and `fix_tool()` stop while `function_when_restart()` is running then continue back to `make project()` and `fix_tool()` :

```
from time import monotonic
from time import monotonic, sleep

start = monotonic()
        while monotonic() - start < (60) : #Run for exactly 1 minute
            # I want the image recognition to always run and if the image pops up I want 
            project()
            sleep(5)
            fix_tool()
```

Answer (score 0):

below can help?

```
while True:
     image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png')
     if image != None:
         project()
         sleep(5)
         fix_tool()
     else:
        pass
```